# User can't authenticate

Tags: python, django

I am using custom authentication with custom user model.

When user authenticates it redirects to the home page, as needed, but the user does not get authenticated.
And when I check in a template `{{user.is_authenticated}}` it says False.

How to fix that?

Here is my backend file for custom authentication:

```
from contracts.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class AuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if not check_password(password, user.password):
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

my view:

```
class LoginView(View):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Added to my setting file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['contracts.auth.backend.AuthBackend']
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'contracts.User'
```

Django version is `2.0.4`

Comment: Try and be a bit more descriptive in your titles. "Not working" isn't a diagnostic. You are more specific about the problem later on, so don't bury that, be up front.

Comment: I can give you one troubleshooting step, maybe you might have done that already. Have you added the path of your custom authentication in the settings files parameter AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND?

Comment: @tadman thanks for your advice, will be more specific next time

Comment: @ArpitGoyal it is already there, updated question

Comment: @AleksandrBaranov You also need to pass in request to your authenticate method. It should return True if user exists, is_active and supplies correct password and false otherwise.

Comment: @SanyamKhurana even if I pass request to my authenticate method, it is not working. And my authenticate method returns User if user exists, with all of the info in it.

Comment: Show us how you are trying to access the user in the template - it seems you are accessing a non-existing template variable.

Comment: @solarissmoke already described it in a question: {{user.is_authenticated}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it when I changed my `login` import:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```